# Salesforce Relational Query

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I have 3 Objects `ObjectA__c`, `ObjectB__c`, `ObjectC__c`.

- `ObjectA__c` looks up to `ObjectB__c`
- `ObjectB__c` looks up to `ObjectC__c`
- `ObjectA__c` and `ObjectC__c` are not related directly.

How do I access the fields of `ObjectC__c` using `ObjectA__c` in a SOQL query?

Answer (score 6):

Via the lookup relationship

```
[Select objb__r.objc__r.field__c from objA__c]
```

Otherwise you could do two queries and collections

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com).

If you're looking for the official name of this type of query, it is **`Right Outer Join`**. The example they give is only one level deep, but I believe this term still applies.

```
SELECT Name, Position__r.Department__c FROM Job_Application__c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookup relations in your queries as described in the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_lookup.htm

For example i want to select names of the the account record owner of my opportunities

```
SELECT account.owner.name from opportunity
```

Keep in mind that you can go up to 5 relations deep with SOQL and that you can also use such a relationships in the where clause:

```
Select id from opportunity where account.owner.name = 'owner'
```